# как сделать правильно анрап в swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
class Person {

    var firstName: String?


    var middleName: String?

    var lastName: String?

    var fullName: String {
        get {
            return ("\(firstName) \(middleName) \(lastName)")
        }
    }

    init (firstName: String, middleName: String, lastName: String) {

        self.firstName = firstName
        self.middleName = middleName
        self.lastName = lastName

    }

}

var person1 = Person(firstName: "23123 ", middleName: " 123123", lastName: "123123 ")
```

когда мы вызываем person1.fullName 
нам приходит Optional("23123 ") Optional(" 123123") Optional("123123") 
нужно не опциональный как это правильно сделать в классе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от optional, вам надо делать force unwrap посредством добавления '!'. Помните, что ваше приложение скрешится, если наткнется на nil, то есть если вы вызовете `firstName!` в момент, когда `firstName == nil`, то это креш.

```
self.firstName = firstName!
```

При этом, я бы сказал, что такое решение неправильное, а правильно будет избавиться от '?' в объявлении переменных инстанса, поскольку вы их все присваиваете в ините.

Comment: есть такой момент что нам может не прийти firstName, и в таком случае var firstName: String? должен остаться

Comment: как сделать в классе проверку по типу 
if firstName != nil { self.firstName = firstName! }
могу ли я вообще так делать в классах 
помогите пожалуйста ;)

Comment: вы можете так делать, код в вашем комментарии абсолютно правильный. я бы порекомендовал если какая то строка пришла nil, заменять на пустую строку - "", так вы точно будете знать что у вас нигде nil после этого встретиться не может. опять же уберете '?'

Comment: я так и поступил просто добавил init на все варианты. Спасибо!

Comment: это, конечно, зависит от приложения, но не лучшая практика заменять nil на пустую строку. Пустая строка - это уже значение, которого сервер на самом деле не передавал. Если это не важно сейчас, может оказаться важно после масштабирования приложения.

Comment: @Igor зависит от ситуации. если например у человека нет middle name, то проще поставить "" а не делать проверку на nil в миллионе мест в приложении.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два хороших варианта, чтобы развернуть (получить не опциональную) переменную:

**Первый:**

```
if let firstName = firstName { // можно задать другое имя, например firslNameNotOptional = firstName
    print("уже развернута - не опциональная")
    print(firstName)
} else {
    print("nil")
    print(firstName)
}
//после блока if firstName остается опциональной!
```

можно сразу оптом:

```
if let firstName = firstName, middleName = middleName, lastName = lastName {
//здесь получим уже не опциональные firstName, middleName, lastName
//но только при условии, что удалось развернуть все три сразу
}
```

*Один важный момент - мы получаем развернутое значение только внутри блока `if {}`*

**Второй:**

```
guard let firstName = firstName else {
    print("firstName - nil")
    return
}

print("уже развернута - не опциональная")
print(firstName)
```

*во всем коде до самого конца метода после guard {} мы получим развернутое firstName*

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Разве это не то, что было нужно?

Comment: та я затупил достаточно было проинициализировать = "" как пустую строку. Ваш ответ тоже был правильный но я использовал другой вариант